# Comparing DFS(recursive) + DP(memoization) vs General Recursion + DP (memoization)

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search, memoization

I have been using DFS + memoization type approach to solve DP problems. Till now it had worked perfectly for every problem. But recently when I tried it for 0/1 knapsack problem it gave TLE in geeksforgeeks but works fine in Leetcode.
General approach is either consider current element or move forward in the array.
But the approach which I use is, I explicitly mention in a **for loop** where it must go. Like for eg either go to 2nd or 3rd or... or 10th element. I have analysed my approach and it seems for me. But i am unable to understand why it gives TLE.

Code of my approach which gives TLE is:

```
int dp[1001][1001];
int util(int indx, int cur_weight, int n,int weights[], int values[]){

if(dp[indx][cur_weight]!=-1)return dp[indx][cur_weight];
int mx_val=0;
for(int i=indx+1;i<n;i++){
    if(cur_weight-weights[i]>=0)
        mx_val=max(mx_val, util(i,cur_weight-weights[i],n,weights,values));
}
dp[indx][cur_weight]=mx_val+values[indx];
return dp[indx][cur_weight];
}

int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n) 
{ 
memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
int mx_val=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(wt[i]<=W)
    mx_val=max(mx_val,util(i,W-wt[i],n,wt,val));
    dp[i][W]=mx_val;
}

return mx_val;
}
```

Code of another solution which uses standard DP solution and **doesn't** give TLE is:

```
int dp[1001][1001];
int answer(int w, int wt[], int val[], int n){
 if(n == 0 || w == 0)
    return 0;
 if(dp[n-1][w] != -1)
    return dp[n-1][w];

 if(wt[n-1] <= w){
    return dp[n-1][w] = max(val[n-1] + answer(w-wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1), answer(w, wt, val, n-1));
 }
   
return dp[n-1][w] = answer(w, wt, val, n-1);

}

int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n) 
{ 
// Your code here
 memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
 return answer(W, wt, val, n);
}
```

Can anyone please help?